# fsevents@2.1.3: Please update to v 2.2.x

Tags: node.js, npm-start

Kindly see the above error that I am receiving while I am doing NPM Start for compiling Sass. Even though I tried to update the version such as this way (npm install -g nodemon npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: Please update to v 2.2.x) but still getting error so please help with that and tell me the solution?

Answer (score -1):

Hello My Gorgeous Friends Out There..!

In reference to above Question that earlier I asked and finally I became to answer it by myself only for those who are newbie and may be in case if they face the same issue so I would like to elaborate regarding the above issue which I faced and I resolved it.

1. I tried many npm commands which I am sure most of you all know it.
2. When I couldn't find any option even on many pages they said do this and this and so on..!
3. Only what I did I Search for ***(Live Sass Compiler)*** in vscode and Boom..! I am Happy with that.

Thanks to Me. :p